Necessary and sufficient condition for distribution dependent agnostic learning
A long time ago, it was shown (Benddek 1991 [1]) that a necessary and sufficient condition for agnostic learning in the distribution-dependent setting is a finite cover.
Later, Max Hopkins [2] showed equivalence between agnostic and realizable learning via a new definition of a cover (a relaxed definition of the classic cover). BUt it was never discussed if having a finite cover over $\mathcal{H}$ with the measure $\mathcal{D}$ is also a necessary and sufficient condition for agnostic learning. Is this known as an open problem or was it shown before that e finite cover also characterizes distribution-dependent learning in the agnostic setting?
I also want to understand the difference between distribution-free and distribution dependent learning in terms of dimension characterization: in distribution-dependent setting, the dimension is not studied as a quantity that takes values in $\mathbb{N}$, but rather a quantity that depends on the distribution (cover, disagreement coefficients ... Vs VC dimension, star number, etc...). Why this difference in characterization the dimensions between the two settings?
[1] Benedek, G. M., & Itai, A. (1991). Learnability with respect to fixed distributions. Theoretical Computer Science, 86(2), 377-389.
[2] Hopkins, M., Kane, D. M., Lovett, S., & Mahajan, G. (2022, June). Realizable learning is all you need. In Conference on Learning Theory (pp. 3015-3069). PMLR.

The latter reference has multiple authors.
